# Java program to check an array maze for clues - answer is always 1 off

Tags: java, maze

I have to make this maze held in an array, and it checks the cell for a two digit number which holds a clue to the next cell. The cell that contains the treasure is one that holds its own coordinates.

In my case, it's cell 52, because it's held in (5, 2), or in this case, (4, 1) since the array starts at 0.

My issue is, my program is reading the numbers 1 off. In the first clue, it leads to 34, which should take me to cell (2, 3). It instead takes me to (1, 2).

I thought it was because of the -1, but since I'm working with human numbers, I need to subtract 1 so it corresponds with 0 as the first instead of 1.

```
public class MazeTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int initRow = 1;
        int initCol = 1;
        Maze myMaze = new Maze();
        myMaze.SetCoordOne(initRow);
        myMaze.SetCoordTwo(initCol);
        System.out.println("Checking the initial cell");
        myMaze.CheckCell();

        while (myMaze.GetFound() == false)
        {
            System.out.println("Checking the next cell.");
            myMaze.ReadClue(myMaze.GetCoordOne() - 1, myMaze.GetCoordTwo() - 1);
            myMaze.NextCell(myMaze.GetClueOne() - 1, myMaze.GetClueTwo() - 1);
            myMaze.CheckCell();
        } 
    }
}

public class Maze
{
    private int[][] mazeCell = {{34, 21, 32, 41, 25}, 
                                {14, 42, 43, 14, 31}, 
                                {54, 45, 52, 42, 23}, 
                                {33, 15, 51, 31, 35}, 
                                {21, 52, 33, 13, 23} };
    private int coordOne;
    private int coordTwo;
    private int clueOne;
    private int clueTwo;
    private boolean found = false;

    public void ReadClue(int row, int col)
    {
        clueOne = mazeCell[row][col] / 10;
        clueTwo = mazeCell[row][col] % 10;
    }   

    public void NextCell(int rowNum, int colNum)
    {
        coordOne = rowNum;
        coordTwo = colNum;
    }

    public void CheckCell()
    {
        System.out.printf("Checking for treasure in %d\n", 
                          mazeCell[coordOne - 1][coordTwo - 1]);
        if (coordOne == clueOne && coordTwo == clueTwo)
        {
                TreasureFound();
        }
    }

    public void TreasureFound()
    {
        System.out.println("Congratulations, you found the treasure!");
        found = true;
    }

    public int GetMazeCell(int row, int col)
    {
        return mazeCell[row][col];
    }

    public int GetCoordOne()
    {
        return coordOne;
    }

    public void SetCoordOne(int num)
    {
        coordOne = num;
    }

    public int GetCoordTwo()
    {
        return coordTwo;
    }

    public void SetCoordTwo(int num)
    {
        coordTwo = num;
    }

    public int GetClueOne()
    {
        return clueOne;
    }

    public void SetClueOne(int num)
    {
        clueOne = num;
    }

    public int GetClueTwo()
    {
        return clueTwo;
    }

    public void SetClueTwo(int num)
    {
        clueTwo = num;
    }

    public boolean GetFound()
    {
        return found;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide if you want to keep clues and coords zero- or one- based.

In `ReadClue` you assign one-based values to clues.

When calling `myMaze.NextCell(myMaze.GetClueOne() - 1, myMaze.GetClueTwo() - 1);` you make coordinates zero-based.

In `CheckCell()` you make a comparison between one-based clues and zero-based coordinates. That's why it doesn't work.

Change your call to NextCell to: `myMaze.NextCell(myMaze.GetClueOne(), myMaze.GetClueTwo());`, this will make both coordinates and clues one-based and your program should work then.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is too many substraction operations in your code.

When you invoke NextCell(), you decrement coords, so you have it indexed from 0.
In the next step, CheckCell() you print a mazeCell with coords decremented again, which may look like it takes you to (1,2) instead of (2,3);

Another thing is, in CheckCell, you compare coords to clues, where coords are already decremented, but clues are not.